# passing filename as arguments in c++

Tags: c++

I have to pass four different text files in an argument in c++ program.
How do i pass??

Comment: This may help: http://www.astro.umd.edu/~dcr/Courses/ASTR615/intro_C/node11.html

Comment: What do you want to pass: the files names? the files contents?

Answer (score 5):

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  std::vector<std::string> args(argv, argv+argc);
  for (size_t i = 1; i < args.size(); ++i) {
    std::string const & aFileName = args[i];
    // Do something with aFileName
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you mean on the command line. When `main` is defined as

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

`argc` is the count of arguments and `argv` contains them. The first arg in the array will be the name of the process and the others are the arguments passed to it.